# Does Watin work with MS EI 10 / Internet explorer 10? Especially the file download and fileupload?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, watin, internet-explorer-10

I have been using Watin (2.1 at the moment) with IE 7 and 8 which has worked ok. With IE 9 there were major problems with programmatically controlling the IE 9 download bar at the bottom of the view, and with using the file upload `ie.FileUpload(...).Set(path)` which takes several minutes before actually entering the file to upload in the file upload dialog.

Has anyone tested if any of this works better with IE 10 than with IE 9?
Would it make sense to install IE 10?
Are there other problems with IE 10?

I am using C#/ASP.NET in Visual studio 2012.

Comment: Upload seems to work fine. I'm just working on file download now.

Comment: Download doesn't work, using the following code:

    FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler(fileName);
    browser.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);

    var link = downloadFileRow.Links.Filter(Find.ByText("Download")).FirstOrDefault();
    link.ClickNoWait();
                        fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);

Comment: I can't reliably get WatiN 2.1 to do file uploads using IE10.